# how to calculate driving duration for gmap in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to calculate driving duration between to place on Google map in rails project.
Is there any way to calculate driving time on Google map?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to begin looking at the Google Map API. This will contain alot of documentation on how to query the API server to obtain the various pieces of information you require for your application:

https://developers.google.com/maps/

This Rails gem may also be of use to you:

https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails

Answer (score 0):

In order to calculate the driving distance you need to use [The Google Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/).

This has very little to do with Rails. In fact, you need to interact with Google Maps API in a programming language you are comfortable with.

If you want to embed the results in a Rails application, you may need to create a Ruby script that performs the task.

I encourage you to have a look at the API documentation to learn more about how using the Google Maps API.